# Exponentiation on the natural numbers. Prove the identities $n^{(m+k)}=n^m \cdot n^k$ and $n^{(m \cdot k)}=(n^m)^k$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Moschovakis, Set theory, Chapter 5, Problem, x.5.3.

Exponentiation on the natural numbers is defined by the following
recursion on $m$:

$n^0=1$,

$n^{Sm}=n^m \cdot n.$

Show that it satisfies the following identities (for $n\neq0$):

$n^{(m+k)}=n^m \cdot n^k$,

$n^{(m \cdot k)}=(n^m)^k.$

ever so grateful

for the help I can get

Comment: By induction on $k$ ? *Basis*: $n^{(m+0)}=n^m=n^m⋅1=n^m⋅n^0$.

Answer (score 0):

First apply your second rule $k$ times in this way: 
$$n^{(m+k)}=n^{S(m+k-1)}=n^{m+k-1}\cdot n=n^{m+k-2}\cdot n\cdot n=\dots=n^m\cdot (\underbrace{n\cdots n\cdot n}_k).\tag{1}$$

Looking at the right hand side, we have $n$ multiplied with itself $k$ times; this can be re-arranged and then we apply the second rule in the "other direction" $k$ times
$$\underbrace{n\cdots n\cdot n}_k=n\cdots n^2\cdot n=\cdots=n^{k-1}\cdot n=n^k.\tag{2}$$
Substitute this into $(1)$ and we're done.

For the second statement, write this as $m\cdot k=\underbrace{m+m+\cdots+m}_k$ and use the statement we just proved, i.e.,

$$n^{(m\cdot k)}=n^{(m+\cdots+m)+m}=n^{m\cdot(k-1)}\cdot n^m=n^{m\cdot(k-2)}\cdot n^m\cdot n^m=\cdots = \underbrace{n^m\cdots n^m}_k=(n^m)^k.$$

The final equality is by using the same method as in $(2)$.